# Insert data into MYSQL Database by invoking python script through SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, mysql, web-services, simplehttpserver

I have the following python script.

```
import  mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'signal', host = '127.0.0.1', port = '1928'
                              ,
                              database = 's_events')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

insert_stmt =   "INSERT INTO t_events (eid)   VALUES ('iosevent123')"


data = 'iosevent123'
cursor.execute(insert_stmt)

cnx.commit()

cnx.close()
```

I also started a simplehttpserver provided by python.

How do I invoke the above script so that the data is inserted into the table?

Comment: Uh, `python name_of_script.py` in the terminal? Or are you asking something else?

Comment: @heyiamt I know how to run it in the terminal. I would like to invoke the  URL like http://localhost:1222/a.py from an IOS app and insert the data into the table. Is that possible?

Comment: gotcha. sorry for the misunderstanding. i think you would need to do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997), where the server acts as a web API. The IOS app would then send a request to the server with instructions to fire a function with the code from your script in it.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant. After starting the minimal http server, what do i do?

Answer (score 1):

Pulling from [this example](https://gist.github.com/bradmontgomery/2219997) as inspiration, run a server on some machine by executing the python script [disclaimer: untested]

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'signal', host = '127.0.0.1', port = '1928'
                              ,
                              database = 's_events')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

class S(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def _set_headers(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()

    def do_GET(self):
        self._set_headers()

        # Assuming the value to insert is just provided in the URL
        # path. e.g., "http://127.0.0.1/<val>"
        i_slash = self.path.index('/')
        val = self.path[(i_slash + 1):]
        insert(val)


def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=S, port=80):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print 'Starting httpd...'
    httpd.serve_forever()

def insert(val):
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO t_events (eid) VALUES ('%s');" % val)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from sys import argv

    if len(argv) == 2:
        run(port=int(argv[1]))
    else:
        run()
```

Once that's running, "simply" send a get request from the IOS app to the server you started. (I quoted "simply" because I have not worked with IOS, but would imagine that pinging APIs is commonplace.)

Comment: It's working, although it's inserting an additional row with value favicon.ico in the table. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Is it a best practice to have the values that we are inserting into database as parameters passed through the URL? What other alternatives do I have?

Comment: @adf_mobile_devoper re: favicon.ico - that string must somehow be coming in though the sting sent in the request. Maybe try grabbing the get request string to find out?

Comment: @adf_mobile_developer re: https message based DB insertions - I agree that that might not be a fantastic solution, particularly if i there is sensitive or PII date being inserted. The thing to do there would be to wrap some encryption around the message being passed, but that's not something I've done before.